# How to set a text at the rectangle with JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

I like to make an app that makes buttons for websites but first I have to put a text at the rectangle. JavaFX has not a method in a rectangle to add text. Can somebody help me?

Comment: How about using a label in javafx whose border is visible and with weight and color of your choice instead of using a rectangle?

Comment: I think I have to use CSS to chance the style but  I have no idea how to use slider to change the style

Answer (score 0):

You can create a StackPane and then add the rectangle and the label

```
StackPane stp= new StackPane();
Rectangle date = new Rectangle();
Text h = new Text(LocalDate.now().toString());
date.setHeight(40);
date.setWidth(120);
h.setTextFill(Color.WHITE);
stp.getChildren().addAll(date,h);
```